# how to get started with docker version of hortonworks after install

Tags: docker, hortonworks-sandbox

I followed the Docker installation (using the bash script) to install Hortonworks Sandbox onto a server via the Docker component.  It is installed on ubuntu 18.04 server.

The install apparently worked.  Now what I want to do is be able to get to the website from other machines in the network.

My IP range is standard 192.168.1.*, however, the sandbox container IP is 172.18.0.2.  I want to reach the container from outside the server it's installed on.  I'm told NAT will work, but I don't know how to work this.

How do I tell Docker/Ubuntu to forward requests to the sandbox?  Or change the sandbox IP to something recognizable by other machines on the network?

Comment: With the `docker run -p` option; you'd have to publish the specific port the server runs on.

Comment: Ok. Here's the problem. There's like 50 ports to pass. Any way to make the container behave like another box on the network?

Comment: ...wow.  I see Hortonworks publishes a VM version of that and it may be easier to set up, and not significantly heavier-weight.

Comment: Thanks David.  Sumit gave me an answer that works. but you are right.  for anyone else I would recommend using the VMs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `docker run --network=host` and all your ports will be listening via your host `ip`.